# JAVAFX - unable to add items to listview

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have a `Tab` called chat. Inside this Tab I have a list of users as `ListView<string>`.
The content of this `ListView` was loaded from FXML file using:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("chat.fxml"))
```

I am trying to add items to my `listview` using java, but when I open the GUI, chat tab, the items I add does not get displayed in the users `listview`.

One of the ways I tried was:

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
listOfUsers.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(values));
```

I have tried other ways as well, but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: the items are not displayed in runtime or in the guibuilder?

Comment: Which version of JFX you use?

Comment: i am using version 2.0, when i run the GUI the users list (list view) appears empty.  (i tried every way possible to add items to it, but they don't appear in the GUI where they should.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks guys..
the problem was that my listView of users was created by the FXML loader, and then by mistake i initialized it again in the java code, so all was needed is deleting the row:

```
listOfUsers=new ListView<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

the file chat.fxml has fx:controller?!

You need...

```
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="DIRECTORY.FILE" //FILE.java
```

Comment: `fx:controller="DIRECTORY.FILE"` file é chatcontroller.java

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
BorderPane pane = null;
    try {
        pane = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(HERENAMECLASS.class.getResource("chat.fxml"));
        pane.getStyleClass().add("main");
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(HERENAMECLASS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```